# TargetInvocationException while trying to test in-app product purchase

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, in-app-purchase

i am trying to test an in-app product purchase for a Windows Phone 8 app in C#

I followed everystep of how to implement such thing 
in this following link : [How to Set Up In-App Purchasing for Your Windows Phone App](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/Articles/2013/07/01/In-App-Purchasing-for-Windows-Phone-8.aspx?Page=2)

the action am trying to do : is **Adding** 50 coins to the current balance by clicking on a `Button`

this is the code :

```
async private void btnBuy50Points_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // 50 Points - Consumable
        var listing = await CurrentApp.LoadListingInformationAsync();
        var fiftypoints =
          listing.ProductListings.FirstOrDefault(
          p => p.Value.ProductId == "coinX" && p.Value.ProductType == ProductType.Consumable);

        try
        {
            receipt = await CurrentApp.RequestProductPurchaseAsync(fiftypoints.Value.ProductId, true);

            if (CurrentApp.LicenseInformation.ProductLicenses[fiftypoints.Value.ProductId].IsActive)
            {
                CurrentApp.ReportProductFulfillment(fiftypoints.Value.ProductId);
                Coins += 50;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

When i debugged : the app crashed with `TargetInvocationException`

at Line :  `var listing = await CurrentApp.LoadListingInformationAsync();`

Comment: What is the inner exception ?

Comment: Can you try calling inside a `Task.Run()` lambda? I have a vague recollection that it doesn't work on the UI thread.

Comment: @PeterTorr-MSFT it works now , turned out , that you must wait till microsoft approves the app-in product submission and then you can test it , what should i do now ? answer my own question ?

Comment: Yes you can answer your own question.

Answer (score 0):

There is no coding bug in my code , i just did the same process after 3 hours and it worked , the problem was that i must wait 2 hours when i submit an In-App Product , and then i can test it.